# How to exclude specific table from innodb buffer pool?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Here's my situation.

I have one really large table that holds about 90 GB of data. I've utilized `DATA DIRECTORY` to place that table on another drive, as I rarely use the table and don't want it wasting space on SSDs. However, I'm having a problem with InnoDB data size.

Both tuning-primer and mysqltuner show InnoDB data size is 73 GB while I've set InnoDB pool size to 30 GB. I'm not really sure where that 73 GB comes from and I think it is because of that very large 90 GB table that I have.

How can I decrease the data size? I know my InnoDB pool size is plenty and I see no adverse impact on my server thus far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need another server for archiving. I used to have this issue and loading up another server purely for archival storage was the best strategy for me. It improved my throughput on the live DB server significantly and still gave access to the archived data on the archival DB server.